# Azure WCF service gives error on blob storage file

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have an Windows Azure project with a WCF service as WebRole.
I have a storage account in Azure where I want to save a file on.

My code worked as I tested with the Azure emulator.

But know I got next error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\BatchAzure.log'.
```

Clientside the service I'm trying to execute:

```
    string path = @"C:\temp\BatchAzure.log";
    var test = service.SaveGezichtBestand(path, "999999");
```

The method I'm using:

```
public bool SaveGezichtBestand(string filePath, string memberID)
        {
            bool result = false;

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to a container 
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("facefileblobcontainer");

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            container.CreateIfNotExist();

            //By default, the new container is private, so you must specify your storage account key (as you did above) 
            //to download blobs from this container.
            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob"
            CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(memberID);

            try
            {
                // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = false;
                throw;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

![enter image description here][1]Hi

I assume that the method SaveGezichtBestand is a method of the wcf service that runs on WindowsAzure. In that case the C drive doesn't have any directories other than the ones the azure depoyment service hase created for you. If you wont to write to a disc on the VM that is hosting your Webrole (in tis case a WCF service) you have to create the directories in your start-up task 
in de *.csdef configation

You also have to add the directorys.cmd file to your wcf project

Remeber that any data on the localdisks of the VM will be lost during a recycle of the VM by Azure.

more info in the Azure traings kit demo "WebAndWorkerRoleEnhancements"

Michiel

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive I follow your situation so to recap...

Your service originally worked locally, but now that you have deployed to azure it does not.  You are consuming your web service from a local client (not on azure and especially not on the web role).

Based off the above the problem is the you are passing a local file path up to azure where your webrole is trying to access the file on its own file system with your path.  To fix this, you need to pass the actual file up to azure (not just the path).  You can use a stream or a byte array.